# Prove the connected components are uncountably many

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ a graph with vertices all the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. An edge exists if and only if the distance between two points is a rational number. Prove that the connected components are uncountably many.

Comment: Are you sure your stated result is correct?

Comment: I have doubts if it is correct as well... it is supposed to be part of an exam, so I can't believe it's wrong untill I have proved so...

Comment: Are you sure that the question stated $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think there is only one connected component of this graph.  Take any two points $P$, $Q$ in $\mathbb{R{^2}}$.  If the distance between them is rational, then there is an edge directly connecting them.  If the distance between them is irrational, say $d$, then choose a rational number, $r$, between $\frac{d}{2}$ and $d$.  Draw circles of radius $r$ around each of $P$ and $Q$.  These two circles will intersect at (at least one) point $S$.  There is an edge from $P$ to $S$ and from $Q$ to $S$, so $P$ and $Q$ are in the same component of the graph.

Comment: This shows not only that the graph is connected but also the stronger result that its diameter is $2$.